# Preventing Pareto smoothed importance sampling (PSIS-LOO) from failing

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, markov-chain-montecarlo, pareto-distribution, importance-sampling

I recently started using Pareto smoothed importance sampling leave-one-out cross-validation (PSIS-LOO), described in these papers:

- Vehtari, A., & Gelman, A. (2015). Pareto smoothed importance sampling. arXiv preprint ([link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02646)).
- Vehtari, A., Gelman, A., & Gabry, J. (2016). Practical Bayesian model evaluation using leave-one-out cross-validation and WAIC. arXiv preprint ([link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04544))

This represents a very enticing approach to out-of-sample model evaluation as it allows to perform LOO-CV with a single MCMC run, and it is allegedly better than existing information criteria such as WAIC.

PSIS-LOO has a diagnostics to tell you whether the approximation is reliable, namely given by the estimated exponents $\hat{k}_i$ of the Pareto distributions fitted to the tails of the empirical distributions of importance weigths (one weight per data point). In short, if an estimated weight $\hat{k}_i \gtrsim 0.7$, bad things can happen.

Sadly, I found that in my application of this method to my problem, for the majority of models of interest I find that a large fraction of the $\hat{k}_i \gg 0.7$. Unsurprisingly, some of the reported LOO log-likelihoods were quite obviously nonsensical (compared to other datasets). As a double-check, I performed a traditional (and time consuming) 10-fold cross-validation, finding that indeed in the above case PSIS-LOO was giving awfully wrong results (on the upside, results were in very good agreement with 10-fold CV for the models in which all $\hat{k}_i \ll 0.7$). For the record, I am using the [MATLAB implementation](https://github.com/avehtari/PSIS) of PSIS-LOO by Aki Vehtari.

Maybe I am just very unlucky in that my current and first problem in which I apply this method is "difficult" for PSIS-LOO, but I suspect that this case might be relatively common. For cases such as mine,  the Vehtary, Gelman & Gabry paper simply says:

> Even if the PSIS estimate has a finite variance, when $\hat{k} > 0.7$, the
>   user should consider sampling directly from $p(\theta^s |y_{−i})$ for the
>   problematic $i$, use $k$-fold cross-validation, or use a more robust
>   model.

These are obvious but not really ideal solutions as they are all time consuming or require additional fiddling (I appreciate that MCMC *and* model evaluation are all about fiddling, but the less the better).

Is there any general method that we can apply beforehand to try and *prevent* PSIS-LOO from failing? I have a few tentative ideas, but I wonder if there is already an empirical solution that people have been adopting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the record, I posted a similar question to the [Stan](http://mc-stan.org/) users mailing list, which you can find [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/stan-users/general/EOF6fhd9EWM). I was answered by one of the authors of the original PSIS-LOO paper and by other contributors of Stan. What follows is my personal summary.

The short answer is that there are no known *general* methods to prevent PSIS-LOO from failing. If PSIS-LOO fails, it is usually because [the model has issues](http://andrewgelman.com/2008/05/13/the_folk_theore/), and fixing it is necessarily left to the user.

Specifically, the reason why PSIS-LOO may fail is usually because one or more LOO distributions are shifted and/or broader than the full posterior, likely due to influential observations, and the importance sampling distribution collapses to one or a few points.

I was thinking that you could try to adopt some form of [parallel posterior tempering](https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/marginal-likelihood-from-tempered-bayesian-posteriors/) approach to solve this issue. The idea is not necessarily wrong, but it was pointed out to me that:

- textbook posterior tempering would still require a lot of case-by-case fiddling to find the right temperature level(s), as there is no obvious nor known way to do that (incidentally, for this reason Stan does not include parallel tempering);
- if you use more than two temperature levels (as it may be required to have a robust approach), the final computational cost approaches that of K-fold cross validation, or of running MCMC on the problematic LOO distributions.

In short, if PSIS-LOO fails, it seems to be hard to get a method that is as robust and general as other simple patches; that's why Vehtari, Gelman & Gabry suggested those methods as per the quote I posted in my original question.